# How is this differential obtained by substitution?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Given the differential equation $$xdy/dx=2y$$ my textbook says that applying the existence and uniqueness theorem obtains us $$y(x)=Cx^2$$ since
$f(x,y)=2y/x$ and the partial derivative of f with respect to y is $2/x$.

I don’t understand at all what kind of substitution happened to get a general solution for $y$

Comment: Actually, the general solution is $y(x)=C x^2$ for $x \ge 0$, $y(x)=D x^2$ for $x < 0$, where $C$ and $D$ can be *different* constants. The existence and uniqueness theorem for $dy/dx = f(x,y) = 2y/x$ doesn't hold at $x=0$, since $f$ is undefined there.

Comment: Also, the phrase “my textbook” is rather useless information. If you're going to mention a book, please tell us *which* book it is (and which page).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $y\not\equiv 0$, it results that:

\begin{align*}
xy' = 2y & \Longleftrightarrow \frac{y'}{y} = \frac{2}{x}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \ln|y| = 2\ln|x| + c\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \ln|y| = \ln|x|^{2} + c\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow y(x) = \pm \exp(c)x^{2}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow y(x) = Cx^{2}
\end{align*}
where $C\in\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}$.

However $y\equiv 0$ is also a solution. Hence $y(x) = Cx^{2}$, for every $C\in\mathbb{R}$.

Hopefully this helps!